# Adjust scrollbar height in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I have created a scrollbar in Tkinter and it's working fine, but the size of the Scroll Button is not being scaled correctly (normally it's adjusted to the size of the scrollable area).

I'm placing all my widgets with a .pack(), therefore the .grid sticky configuration is something I would like to avoid.

My question is: Which part of the scrollbar configuration is responsible for scaling the height?

The code example:

```
    master = Tk()
    FrameBIG = Frame(master)
    Main = Canvas(FrameBIG,height = 1200,width =1500,scrollregion=Main.bbox("all"))
    scroll = Scrollbar(FrameBIG ,orient="vertical", command=Main.yview)
    scroll.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    Main.pack(side = BOTTOM, anchor = NW,fill="x")
    FrameBIG.pack(anchor = W, fill = "x")
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. We can't debug code that we cannot see. The final height of the scrollbar is a factor both of how the scrollbar is configured, and how it is added to the window.

Comment: I think you are trying to have your scrollbar change size with the window correct?

Comment: Which version of python are you using? 2.x or 3.x? (you can get the version with `python --version` or `python3 --version`)

Comment: Your code doesn't run. Please provide code that  is complete and functional.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code

```
Main = Canvas(FrameBIG,height=1200,width=1500,scrollregion=Main.bbox("all"))
```

is wrong because `Main` does not exists yet. It should be

```
Main = Canvas(FrameBIG,background="blue", height = 500,width =500)
Main.configure(scrollregion=Main.bbox("all"))
```

But it is meaningless because `Main` canvas was created right now and is empty (so the `bbox` method returns `None`)

When you created the scrollbar with

```
scroll = Scrollbar(FrameBIG ,orient="vertical", command=Main.yview)
```

you forgot to complete the **two step contract** between `scroll` and `Main`, so you have to add the line below (just after the creation of `scroll`)

```
Main.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
```

Now the code is like this

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
FrameBIG = Frame(master)

Main = Canvas(FrameBIG,background="blue", height = 500,width =500)
Main.configure(scrollregion=Main.bbox("all"))

scroll = Scrollbar(FrameBIG ,orient="vertical", command=Main.yview)
Main.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

scroll.pack(side="right", fill="y")
Main.pack(side = BOTTOM, anchor = NW,fill="x")
FrameBIG.pack(anchor = W, fill = "x")

master.mainloop()
```

Now you can notice that the scroll bar does not have the button. Its because the `Main` canvas is empty. Let's add something to the `Main` canvas

```
FrameBIG.pack(anchor = W, fill = "x")

# creates a diagonal from coordinates (0,0) to (500,1000)
Main.create_line(0, 0, 500, 1000)

master.mainloop()
```

Now the line is there but the scroll button is not there yet, why?
Because you have to update the `scrollregion` of the `Main` canvas.
So let's do it with

```
FrameBIG.pack(anchor = W, fill = "x")

Main.create_line(0, 0, 500, 1000)
Main.configure(scrollregion=Main.bbox("all"))

master.mainloop()
```

Now it is working properly.
Here the complete code.

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
FrameBIG = Frame(master)

Main = Canvas(FrameBIG,background="blue", height = 500,width =500)
Main.configure(scrollregion=Main.bbox("all"))

scroll = Scrollbar(FrameBIG ,orient="vertical", command=Main.yview)
Main.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

scroll.pack(side="right", fill="y")
Main.pack(side = BOTTOM, anchor = NW,fill="x")
FrameBIG.pack(anchor = W, fill = "x")

Main.create_line(0, 0, 500, 1000)
Main.configure(scrollregion=Main.bbox("all"))

master.mainloop()
```

**In the next question, post a question with a complete working code that shows up you problem. You will get faster and better answers, ok?**
Have a nice day.